# Powershell JSON Manipulation

Tags: json, powershell

```
$parent = @"
{
    "Property1":  "Property1Value",
    "Description":  "Generic Description",
    "SubProperties":  {
                       
                       "SubSubTemplateProps": {
                                    SubSubSubTemplateProps1 : "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                    SubSubSubTemplateProps2 : {
                                                                  SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1 : [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "Key":  "Name",
                                                                            "Value":  "Temp"
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                            "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                            }
                            }
                   }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$templateobj = $parent.SubProperties.SubSubTemplateProps

$parent.SubProperties.psobject.Properties.Remove("SubSubTemplateProps")


for($j = 0; $j -lt 3; $j++)
{
$i = "{0:D2}" -f ($j+1)
$letters = @("a","b","c")
    foreach($letter in $letters)
    {
        $newobject = $templateobj
        ($newobject.SubSubSubTemplateProps2.SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1 | ? {$_.key -eq "Name"}).Value = "NewValue$letter$i"
        $parent.SubProperties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubSubProp$letter$i" -Value $newobject
    }

}
$parent |convertto-json -Depth 100
```

Im expecting output like this:

```
{
    "Property1":  "Property1Value",
    "Description":  "Generic Description",
    "SubProperties":  {
                          "SubSubPropa01":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValuea01"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            },
                          "SubSubPropb01":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValueb01"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            },
                          "SubSubPropa02":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValuea02"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            },
                          "SubSubPropb02":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValueb02"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            }
                      }
}
```

But I get output like this where all of the noteproperties of the parent are updated instead of just the noteproperty I added. WHAT?!

```
{
    "Property1":  "Property1Value",
    "Description":  "Generic Description",
    "SubProperties":  {
                          "SubSubPropa01":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValueb02"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            },
                          "SubSubPropb01":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValueb02"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            },
                          "SubSubPropa02":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValueb02"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            },
                          "SubSubPropb02":  {
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps1":  "SubSubSubTemplateProps1",
                                                "SubSubSubTemplateProps2":  {
                                                                                "SubSubSubSubTemplateProps1":  [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "Name",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "NewValueb02"
                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                       "Key":  "SupSubSubProp2",
                                                                                                                       "Value":  "Supprop2value"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                               ]
                                                                            }
                                            }
                      }
}
```

Can someone suggest how to copy a node and replace a sub value then add it back to the parent without it overwriting all other child nodes? Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What part of this do you think is *copying* a node?

Comment: Most objects in .NET/PowerShell are passed by _reference_, so what you're doing is just editing the same object multiple times, while adding new references to it to the object hierarchy.

Comment: I was thinking $newobject = $templateobj is creating a new pscustomobject with the info from the $templateobj

Comment: @JonathanMills no, that doesn't work like that. `$newobject = $templateobj` just copies the object reference held by `$templateobj` to `$newobject`. Normally you'd construct a hashtable (eg. `$templateobj = @{}`) and then do `$newobject = [pscustomobject]$templateobj` to create a brand new custom object based on the contents of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem, as explained in the comments and in more detail in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58241314/45375) is:

- **`[pscustomobject]` instances, such as returned by `ConvertFrom-Json` are instances of a .NET *reference type***, which means that `$newobject = $templateobj` doesn't create a *copy* of the *object* stored in `$templateobj` in `$newobject`, it creates a copy of the *reference* to object `$templateobj`, so that `$templateobj` and `$newobject` end up pointing to the *very same object*. Only instances of .NET *value types* are *themselves* copied with simple assignments - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461078/45375) for background information.
  Therefore, **you ended up repeatedly modifying the very same object instead of independent copies of it**.
- While **`$templateobj.psobject.Copy()` is a convenient method to create a *shallow* clone (copy) of a `[pscustomobject]` instance**, it isn't sufficient in your case, because your instances also contain reference-type instances among the object's *property values*, which then again get copies as *references*.
  In other words: **your template object is a `[pscustomobject]` *graph* (nested), so it requires *deep*-cloning, for which there is no built-in method.**

  - Note: **If you know the structure of the template object ahead of time**, there are **simpler and more efficient solutions**:

    - Use a *literal* `[pscustomobject]` object definition *inside your loop*, which creates a new instance every time - see [the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58241314/45375).
    - Construct your template as an ordered [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`[ordered] @{ ... }`), and cast it to `[pscustomobject]` every time you need a new copy inside the loop - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69827922/45375)
    - Define a custom `class` and instantiate it in every loop iteration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115554/45375).

---

If you *do* need **deep-cloning of `[pscustomobject]` graphs**, use **helper function 
`Copy-PSCustomObject`**, defined further below, with the `-Deep` switch:

```sh
$newobject = Copy-PSCustomObject -Deep $templateobj
```

**Helper function `Copy-PSCustomObject`:**

Note: This is *not* a *generic* deep-cloning function that works with objects of *any* type (which would be impossible to implement), but it should work with `[pscustomobject]` graphs such as returned by `ConvertFrom-Json`, which limits their composition to:

- Primitive JSON types that map onto primitive .NET types and `[string]`, all of which either are .NET *value types* or, in the case of `[string]` act like them.
- *Nested* `[pscustomobject]` instances with the same composition.
- *Arrays* of either.

```sh
function Copy-PSCustomObject {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [PSCustomObject] $InputObject,
    [switch] $Deep
  )

  begin {
    if ($Deep) {
      # Helper script block (anonymous function) for walking the object graph
      $sb = {
        param($original)
        $copy = $original.psobject.Copy()
        foreach ($prop in $copy.psobject.Properties) {
          if ($prop.Value -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]) { # Presumed array
            $prop.Value = @($prop.Value) # Clone array
            foreach ($i in 0..($prop.Value.Count-1)) {
              $prop.Value[$i] = & $sb $prop.Value[$i] # Recurse
            }
          }
          elseif ($prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
            $prop.Value = & $sb $prop.Value # Recurse
          }
          # Otherwise: assume it is a value type or string and needs no cloning.
        }
        # Output the deep-cloned object
        $copy
      }  
    }

  }

  process {
    if ($Deep) {
      & $sb $InputObject
    }
    else {
      # Shallow copy.
      $InputObject.psobject.Copy()
    }
  }
}
```