# Powershell array changes contents unexpectedly

Tags: arrays, powershell

`enter code here`I have a powershell script with an arrary formed like this:

```
$trace = [PSCustomObject]@{
            number  = -1
            times   = @()
            address = ""
            ip      = ""
        }
```

This is in a loop so there are numerous values assigned as above.
Then, a larger array is formed:

```
$traces += $trace
```

Later, in the script, I see that $traces.number contents have unexpectedly changed.  So I output its contents in a series using

```
Write-Host "200 traces.number" $traces.number
```

This results in

```
200 traces.number 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10    
200 traces.number 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10    
200 traces.number 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9    
200 traces.number 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9
```

The size of the array remains at 10 but the value "6" is repeated.
The line of code preceding this change is:

```
for ($j3 = 0; $j3 -lt $routecountless1; $j3++) { $route3[$j3].number = $j3 + 1 }
```

$route3 is an entirely different array so it seems there would be no action on $traces.
There are 5 other lines of code that do the same thing on $route1 ... $route6 and nothing like this appears to be happening with any of those.  The indexing variables are all different $j1, $j2....

It looks like the $traces.number array is being overwritten.  But how to figure that out and how to prevent?

Comment: As an aside: Extending arrays in a loop with `+=` is inefficient, because a _new_ array must be created behind the scenes _in every iteration_, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to use a `foreach` loop as an _expression_ and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `[array] $outputs = foreach (...) { ... }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375). In case you need to create arrays manually, e.g. to create _multiple_  ones, use an efficiently extensible list type - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029146/45375).

Answer (score 1):

> `$route3` is an entirely different array so it seems there would be no action on `$traces`.

In .NET, which PowerShell is built on, it **comes down to [*reference types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) vs. [*value types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)**; `[string]` is an exception in that is treated like a value type, even though it is technically a reference type.

`[pscustomobject]` is a *reference type*, so any number of variables / array elements may "point" (store a *reference to*) to a given, single instance of this type, so that updates to this instance are invariably reflected in all those variables / array elements.

For example:

```bash
# Create a (single-element) array that contains (references) 
# a [pscustomobject] instance.
$trace = , [pscustomobject] @{ number = 42 }

# Create another array that references the *same* [pscustomobject] instance.
$route3 = , $trace[0]

# Updating the .number property of the [pscustomobject] instance
# affects *both* arrays.
$route3[0].number = 43

# Print the updated [pscustomobject] instance referenced from both arrays.
# -> 43, 43
$trace[0].number, $route3[0].number
```

---

> how to figure that out?

- To **test if a given value is an instance of a reference type**, use the negated return value of the type's `.IsValueType` property; e.g. (building on the above):

  ```bash
  # $trace[0] contains a [pscustomobject] instance.
  $trace[0].GetType().IsValueType # -> $false -> is reference-type instance
  ```
- To **test if two values reference the very same instance of a reference type**, use `[object]::ReferenceEquals()`:

  ```bash
  [object]::ReferenceEquals($trace[0], $route3[0]) # -> $true
  ```

---

> how to prevent?

In order **to get an *independent copy* of a *reference-type* instance, you must *clone* it, i.e. create a *new instance* of it that contains the same data.**

The challenge is that **there is *no* universal cloning mechanism**, especially if the cloning must be *deep* (recursive) in order to ensure that *nested* values are independent copies too.

Copying an instance's members as-is (*member-wise* cloning, a.k.a *shallow* cloning) only creates independent values for those members that happen to contain value-type instances. That is, those properties in the original object that contain (reference) reference-type instances will have the clone's properties reference the very same instances.

While .NET does provide an [`ICloneable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ICloneable) interface, its behavior is ill-specified (shallow vs. deep cloning, cloning all members as-is vs. selective modifications) and even not recommended for use in public APIs.

The root of .NET's type hierarchy, `System.Object`, has a *protected*  (i.e., *non-public*) [`.MemberWiseClone()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone), which facilitates member-wise cloning, which classes can take advantage of *if* they choose to publicly expose cloning functionality. The linked documentation page contains a more detailed discussion of shallow vs. deep cloning.

In practice, **two .NET types frequently used in PowerShell offer methods that perform *shallow* cloning**:

- [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) (a.k.a `[psobject]`) has a `.Copy()` instance method, which must be accessed via the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject).
- [`[array]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) has a `.Clone()` method (which is therefore available on arrays of *any* type, including the `[object[]]` arrays PowerShell constructs by default).

  - A convenient - albeit inefficient - way to create a copy of a collection of any type *as an `[object[]]` array* is to use `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) - that is, it enumerates the elements of a given collection and collects them in an `[object[]]` array.

A modified version of the example above with a manually cloned `[pscustomobject]` instance:

```bash
# Create a (single-element) array that contains (references) a
# [pscustomobject] instance.
$trace = , [pscustomobject] @{ number = 42 }

# Create another array that references 
# a *shallow clone* of that [pscustomobject] instance.
$route3 = , $trace[0].psobject.Copy()

# Updating the .number property of the [pscustomobject] instance
# in the other array now only affects that array.
$route3[0].number = 43

# Print the updated [pscustomobject] instance referenced from both arrays, 
# which are now DIFFERENT numbers.
# -> 42, 43 
$trace[0].number, $route3[0].number
```

---

A ***limited* deep-cloning implementation for `[pscustomobject]` graphs** can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71606332/45375):

It limits deep-cloning to `[pscustomobject]` instances and arrays / collections therefore (if a collection isn't an array, it is cloned as an array). This is sufficient for object graphs returned from [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), for instance, but not for arbitrary object graphs containing instances of other reference types.

The linked helper function, `Copy-PSCustomObject`, when invoked with `-Deep`, automatically provides the functionality shown in this simplified example:

```bash
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ numProp = 42; arrayProp = 'foo', 'bar' }

# Create a *shallow* clone, using .psobject.Copy()
# !! This alone is NOT enough, because .arrayProp in the 
# !! copy points to the very same array as $obj.arrayProp.
# !! You would see this if you did $obj.arrayProp[0] = 'new', for instance.
$copy = $obj.psobject.Copy()

# Now make the copy a *deep* clone by (shallow-)cloning the array.
# !! *Shallow*-cloning the array is enough in *this case*, because
# !! all array elements are *strings*, which are treated like value types.
# !! If (other) reference-type instances were among the elements,
# !! *recursion* would be needed, which Copy-PSCustomObject -Deep
# !! does, but only with respect to [pscustomobject] and nested collections.
# !! Now, $obj.arrayProp[0] = 'new2' wouldn't affect $copy.arrayProp[0] anymore.
$copy.arrayProp = @($obj.arrayProp)
```