# PowerShell, unexpected different results depending upon what is removed from a JSON structure

Tags: powershell, variables, psobject

Hoping that someone might be able to explain why the first removal does not affect the first variable, but the second removal does affect the first variable, please.  Thank you.

```
    $X = @'
    {
      "$schema": "myschema",
      "parameters": {
        "avSetName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "faultDomains": {
          "type": "int",
          "defaultValue": 2
        }
      },
      "variables": {
        "templateRef": "singleavset v1",
        "osProfile9": "blahblah"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
          "name": "[parameters('avSetName')]",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
      ]
    }
    '@
 
 
    # this affects only $B...
    $A = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $X
    $B = $A.PSObject.Copy()
    $A
    $B
    $B.PSObject.Properties.Remove( "variables" )
    $A
    $B
 
 
    # this affects $A and $B...
    $A = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $X
    $B = $A.PSObject.Copy()
    $A
    $B
    $B.Variables.PSObject.Properties.Remove( "osprofile9" )
    $A
    $B
```

When loading $B, then if I simply use   $B = $A   then I get why $A would be affected, because PowerShell is I believe using a reference pointer behind the scenes.   But, if I use  $B = $A.PSObject.Copy()  then I would not expect $A to be affected.

Comment: Seems like an issue with the way the ConvertFrom-Json is creating the PSobject table, not sure what the cause is, but a way around it is:

`$A | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json`

rather than a copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.Copy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject.Copy) method of type `[pscustomobject]` creates a *shallow* clone (copy) of a given instance rather than a *deep* clone (and the type fundamentally doesn't offer deep copying).

Thus, **any *nested* `[pscustomobject]` instances in your input object - by virtue of being instances of .NET *reference types* - are *not* copied**; specifically, **it is a *reference* to them that gets copied**, which means that both the input object and its copy **point to (reference) *the very same nested instance***. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73942472/45375) for background information.

Specifically, this relates to your modifications as follows:

- In your first modification, you're removing a *property* from the copied object: since the original object and its copy *as a whole* are by definition distinct instances, this removal affects the copy only.
- In your second modification, you're removing a property from a property *value* (`.Variables.PSObject.Properties.Remove( "osprofile9" )`, and that *value* (`.Variables`) - due to being a nested `[pscustomobject]` instance - is *shared* between the original and the copy, i.e. they both reference the very same instance. Therefore, modification of this nested instance surfaces in *both* the copy and the original.

Since your data source is ultimately JSON, the simplest way to create two fully independent `[pscustomobject]` instances is to call [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) *twice*, and capture each call in a separate variable:

```
$A = ConvertFrom-Json $X
$B = ConvertFrom-Json $X
```

Comment: Thank you squire.  Excellently explained.